# InfoPath attachment in a repeating table

Tags: list, sharepoint, attachment, infopath

First of all, Thank You. Here is my Boondoggle...

Currently, users are required to do regular training which is printed 
and stored in user's manila folder.
My objective:
Create a SharePoint List page with InfoPath forms for each training item.
Included in this form:

Training Title/Description/Due date

User Name - Repeating table pulled from a data connection to a SharePoint list with "User Names". 
(60 users max, this list also has title, name, phone number)

A PDF attachment for their certificate of completion.

EXAMPLE:
    Blow your nose today. 
    Due Date 08-23-2013

```
Name           Attachment
Joe Smith      XZX.PDF
Bill Smith     YYY.PDF
Jack Smith     ZXZ.PDF
```

I am able to create the repeating table list of names from the 'user names' List.
But, I cannot figure out a way to attach a file to each name individually.
I add a file and it populates the entire list.

```
Joe Smith      AAA.PDF
Bill Smith     AAA.PDF
Jack Smith     AAA.PDF
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you copying the data from the SharePoint list data source into the main data source, or simply displaying it from the secondary data source? Since you can't (reasonably) modify the secondary data source to add new fields to it, if you want to associate new data with each row, I think you'll need to copy the data in to the main data source. This is also necessary if you want to be able to submit the forms and re-open them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am placing a repeating table with a secondary data source to populate the table. I do not believe I am copying the data in that sense. And yes, you are correct, I would like to be able to re-open the form as users add their own PDF (attachment) to the form.